# Maximum of Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose $X_t = e^{-t}W_{e^{2t}}$ is an Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process ($W_t$ is a Wiener process). I'd like to show that for all $ 0 < a < b $,

$$
\mathbb{P}\Big( \max_{0 \leq t \leq a} X_t = \max_{0 \leq t \leq b} X_t\Big) = \frac{a}{b}.
$$

I know I need to use the stationarity and Markov property of the Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process, but I'm not sure how to. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably mean $X_t = e^{-t}W_{e^{2t}}$ instead. In either case, the important part is that $X_t$ is stationary and Markov, as you said. Put $$D_n = \left\{\frac{bk}{2^n} \mid k = 0, 1, \dots, 2^n\right\}$$
and $a_n$ the minimal member of $D_n$ which is at least $a$; this is exactly $a_n = \frac{b}{2^n} \cdot \lceil \frac{2^n a}{b} \rceil$. Note that $a_n \to a$ and is monotone decreasing.

Now consider $$P \left( \max_{0 \leq t \leq a_n} X_t = \max_{0 \leq t \leq b} X_t \right).$$
By continuity of measure, this sequence converges to the desired probability $$P \left( \max_{0 \leq t \leq a} X_t = \max_{0 \leq t \leq b} X_t \right),$$
but we know that by the fact that $X_t$ is stationary and Markov that $X_t$ on any interval $\left[\frac{k}{2^n}, \frac{k+1}{2^n}\right]$ has the same law as $X_t$ on any other such interval of the same length, and so the maximum of the process happens with uniform probability in any given one of those intervals, of which $0 \leq t \leq a_n$ contains $\lceil \frac{2^n a}{b} \rceil$. So
$$
P \left( \max_{0 \leq t \leq a} X_t = \max_{0 \leq t \leq b} X_t \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( \max_{0 \leq t \leq a_n} X_t = \max_{0 \leq t \leq b} X_t \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{ \left\lceil \frac{2^n a}{b} \right\rceil}{2^n} = \frac{a}{b}.
$$

Edit: I hand waved the calculation of the probability above. More precisely, we will do the following case for ease, though the general situation is not much harder. Let $X_t = e^{-t}W_{e^{2t}}$; we will show $$P\left(\max_{0 \leq t \leq 1/2} X_t \leq \max_{1/2 \leq t \leq 1} X_t\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$ explicitly. In particular, consider the time-reversed process $Y_t = X_{1-t} = e^{1-t}W_{e^{2 - 2t}}$. One can check that $E[Y_t] = 0$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(Y_t, Y_s) = e^{-|t-s|}$, so that $Y_t$ is also an OU process identical in law to $X_t$. Then, $$P\left(\max_{0 \leq t \leq 1/2} X_t \leq \max_{1/2 \leq t \leq 1} X_t\right) = P\left(\max_{0 \leq t \leq 1/2} Y_t \leq \max_{1/2 \leq t \leq 1} Y_t\right) = P\left(\max_{1/2 \leq t \leq 1} X_t \leq \max_{0 \leq t \leq 1/2} X_t\right)$$
so the maximum of $X_t$ on $[0,1]$ occurs with equal probability in $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2, 1]$. The same logic extended gives the claim asked about in the comment.

Comment: "we know by the fact that $X_t$ is stationary and Markov [...] the maximum of the process happens with uniform probability in any given one of those intervals". Could you provide more details or a reference please ?

Comment: Right, I suppose I was a little vague. I'll add an edit.

Comment: As a followup question, would you know if the same formula holds if $X_t$ is replaced by its absolute value $|X_t|$; that is, $$
\mathbb{P}\Big( \max_{0 \leq t \leq a} |X_t| = \max_{0 \leq t \leq b} |X_t|\Big) = \frac{a}{b}?
$$ I guess it would boil down to whether $|X_t|$ is stationary and Markov.

Comment: Seems true by a more or less identical argument, unless I am missing something. I guess I should note for posterity that the time-reversal argument actually relies on OU processes being homogenous so that the distribution is identical under time reversal, which is in fact stronger than being stationary. But you can do it with stationarity, i.e. by just noting that conditional on the starting point, all the intervals are identical and independent.